# SDL (Simple MediaDirect Layer) trying to scale my sprite (character)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, 2d, sdl

I am just trying to scale (make bigger proportionally) my character based on windows weight and height. How can I do that?
I tried SDL_BlitScaled(newsurface, NULL, screen, NULL); but it did not work.
My code:

```
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);
SDL_Surface* mySprite = IMG_Load( SPRITE_PNG_PATH);

SDL_Rect rcSprite;
rcSprite.x = 250;
rcSprite.y = 100;

SDL_BlitSurface(mySprite, NULL, screen, &rcSprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to have a middle surface, whose width and height are your game's native resolution. You then render the entire frame to this surface, and render that surface to the window using the `SDL_BlitScaled` function.

For example, if you want your native resolution to be 600x400, you would create a 600x400 surface, blit your character and whatever else to that surface, and then finally scaled blit that surface to the window. If you resize your window to 1200x800, everything will look twice as big.

```
SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);

// Create a surface with our native resolution
int NATIVE_WIDTH = 600;
int NATIVE_HEIGHT = 400;
SDL_Surface* frame = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, NATIVE_WIDTH, NATIVE_HEIGHT, 
    screen->format->BitsPerPixel, screen->format->Rmask, 
    screen->format->Gmask, screen->format->Bmask, screen->format->Amask);
assert(frameSurface);

SDL_Surface* mySprite = IMG_Load( SPRITE_PNG_PATH);

SDL_Rect rcSprite;
rcSprite.x = 250;
rcSprite.y = 100;

// Blit everything to the intermediate surface, instead of the screen.
SDL_BlitSurface(mySprite, NULL, frame, &rcSprite);

// Once we've drawn the entire frame, we blit the intermediate surface to
// the window, using BlitScaled to ensure it gets scaled to fit the window.
SDL_BlitScaled(frame, NULL, screen, NULL);
```

Comment: Collin, thanks a lot it is working. I tried very similar to what you have but did not work before. I must have missed something.   I have one more question what if you have mulitiple images. one is sprite and another is background (both are png and loaded with IMG_Load() and rendered with SDL_BlitSurface()). Do I call SDL_BlitScaled() for each of those two images? Currently my background is complete black when I use your code for the sprite (it is scaled though).

Comment: I'm guessing you are using SDL 1.2 and if so, why not switch to SDL 2.0 which has more features and support now. You could then simply use SDL_RenderCopyEx with a larger destination SDL_Rect to scale your image to the render target.

Comment: Zammalad I am using SDL 2.0 but for some reason I cannot mix SDL_Surface with SDL_Renderer. Nothing gets drawn.